# Does it matter what I name a C file?

Tags: c

In Java, it is required by the compiler to name your files `<Classname>.java`. In C, does it matter what the file name is?

Comment: Only to the extent that it helps you understand your code. :)

Comment: I bet there are restrictions in the name's length and the characters allowed.

Comment: No. (It seems that a quick test would have answered this for you much quicker than a question here.)

Comment: @alk only as enforced by the filesystem/buildutility/etc, not by `C`

Comment: Keep in mind that whatever development system you have is likely to have restrictions.

Comment: @cmd: please see my answer on this.

Comment: @KenWhite I tried googling it, but there was no apparent answer. A quick test might have worked, but when other people want to know this, they might google it first as well.

Comment: @mathguy54: Or they might just have tested it as well. :-) It's much easier for me to open calc.exe to do a quick calculation than it is to google an answer, then navigate here, post a question, and wait for an answer. Not every simple task needs to be solved via Google. There's value in self-learning through exerting some effort on your own as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the source files can in principle be called anything. However, the name should reflect the contents of the file for readability. Header files also don't *have* to be called the same as the corresponding source files; they just *should*.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [C89 draft standard](http://web.archive.org/web/20050207005628/http://dev.unicals.com/papers/c89-draft.html) (but similar limitations exists for more recent standards as well), section [3.8.2](http://web.archive.org/web/20050207005628/http://dev.unicals.com/papers/c89-draft.html#3.8.2):

> There shall be an implementation-defined mapping between the delimited sequence and the external source file name. The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or more letters (as defined in 2.2.1) followed by a period (.) and a single letter. The implementation may ignore the distinctions of alphabetical case and restrict the mapping to six significant characters before the period.

thus an implementation **may** pose some limits on the names of included files and probably is likely that these limits would be valid also for any source file (not only `#include`d ones).

On modern implementations the limits on the length of the file name should not be too strict, but I'd stick to plain ASCII when naming a source file. Anyhow, the docs for your compiler of choice should mention the possible limitations.

Addendum: according to latest C99 draft (ISO-IEC 9899-TC3, aka [WG14/N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)) in annex J (portability issues), there is (emphasis mine):

> ### J.3 Implementation-defined behavior
>
> A conforming implementation ***is required to document*** its choice of behavior in each of
>   the areas listed in this subclause. The following are implementation-defined: 
>   [...]
>
> #### J.3.11 Preprocessing directives
>
> [...]
>   - How sequences in both forms of header names are mapped to headers or external
>   source file names (6.4.7).

This confirms my statement above also for C99: implementations **may** impose limitations on valid source file names (and **must** document which).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no requirement for anything inside the file to match the name of the file. However some C compilers dislike names that don't end in one of several extensions. As an example GCC tries to detect whether a file is C or C++ by looking at the extension .c for C .i for C that has already been run through the preprocessor so shouldn't be run through the C preprocessor again and .C(capital C vs the earlier lowercase c), .cc .cpp, .cxx, .ii(like .i only for C++) and a few more for C++.

Comment: To expand on this, anything *before* the extension is fair game.

Comment: "GCC tries to detect ..." On the plus side, it'll happily accept just about any extension when you *tell* it what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

The only restriction seems to be that files to be `#include`ed may only contain characters from the *Source Character Set*, that is the character set allowed to write the actual source code in.

So to turn this around: If you do not `#include` a file C does not put any restictions on the naming.

For details please the the C-Standard 6.4.7 and 5.2.1 (for Source Character Set).

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling multiple C files into one executable you want to make sure each of them has their own unique name.

Answer (score 0):

No, in C language it's not necessary, but for readability the name files must content a name related to his content and they must be unique.